# SQL Server 2000 how to form a case within a case statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to have a case statement within a case's when true then statement?

```
case when true then 
   case when false then 'test0'
   else 'test1'
   end
else
    case when false then 'test2'
    else 'test3'
    end
end
```

Note sure where to put the end statements?

Comment: Yes. As long as you make sure to place an `end` after each case statement.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. The Case expression does not know it is embedded in another case expression. Each Case expression needs an End keyword:

```
Select Case
        When Foo = Bar Then 'Test0'
        Else Case
                When Gamma = Theta Then 'Test1'
                End
        End
```

Another way is to simply stack the expressions

```
Select Case
        When Foo = Bar Then 'Test0'
        When Gamma = Theta Then 'Test1'
        Else 'Blah'
        End
```

When stacked like this, the expressions are executed in the order they are written until one When expression evaluates to true (i.e., you get to one of the Then expressions).

Answer (score 1):

It may be good to use parenthesis or identation (or both) so it's obvious which `case` goes with which `end`.

```
case when true then 
  (  case when false then 'test0'
     else 'test1'
     end
  ) 
else
  ( case when false then 'test2'
    else 'test3'
    end
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the parenthesis, that definitely help separate out the logic for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good as is.  its ok to have the End End next to each other as the interpreter understands the embedding.